# Consolidate JSON objects in a single unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, menu

I am working with AJAX, JSON and jQuery/JavaScript to try and build out a hierarchical navigational menu: Categories / Sections / Articles

All the items that need to appear in the menu are stored as objects in 3 separate JSON files (one file for Categories, one for Sections, and one for Articles). I rely on 3 separate AJAX calls to grab the objects in the JSON files and then post them as hyperlinked items in three corresponding unordered lists: Categories, Sections, Articles.

There are many challenges facing me as I continue with my efforts to construct the navigational menu, but I think the next step is to figure out how to get all JSON objects to post to a SINGLE unordered list in my HTML – rather than a separate list for each of the 3 AJAX calls. (This should make it easier for me to then start sorting the items so that the menu has the proper structure. For example, I will eventually need for each Section to sit below the Category that is its actual parent.) Hoping that someone can guide me on how to adjust my code here.

My AJAX calls are below. Would like for all 3 calls to dump the JSON objects to the SAME unordered list. Currently -- the objects end up in 3 separate lists. Thanks much in advance.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/categories.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul id="categories" />');
    let html = data.categories.map(c => `<li class="cat"><a href="${c.html_url}">${c.name}</a></li>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#testnav');
  }
  });

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/sections.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul id="sections" />');
    let html = data.sections.map(s => `<li class="sec" categoryID=${s.category_id}><a href="${s.html_url}">${s.name}</a></li>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#testnav');
  }
  });

  $.ajax({
  url: 'https://myURL/articles.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: 'false',
  success: function(data) {
    let $ul = $('<ul id="articles" />');
    let html = data.articles.map(a => `<li class="art" sectionID=${a.section_id}><a href="${a.html_url}">${a.name}</a></li>`);
    $ul.append(html).appendTo('#testnav');
  }
  });
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Interesting remark. I see the term 'JSON Object' used extensively by reputable organizations like the W3C as well as the W3 Schools. Here is just one reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: You won't find "JSON object" used by the w3c. And w3 schools is all but a "reputable organization" because of such problems. They are only really good in SEO. You're better off with the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/XML/EXI/docs/json/exi-for-json.html#N65908